# Generating all possible combination from two json array list using dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb

I am working on mule 3.9. While working i came across a scenario, where i want to generate all possible combination of vales from incoming JSON array list. The values under json array list are dynamic.

I want to generate the output in the xml format. I want to achieve this only using dataweave. Please help me how to achieve this in mule 3.9 using datawevae.

Below is my JSON input and required xml output.

Note: Json arrray list are dynamic

JSON Input

```
 "building":[  
      {  
         "code":"BuildingExcess",
         "value":"600"
      },
      {  
         "code":"BuildingExcess",
         "value":"700"
      }
   ],
"content":[  
      {  
         "code":"ContentExcess",
         "value":"600"
      },
      {  
         "code":"ContentExcess",
         "value":"400"
      }
]
```

Output

```
  <resultset>
    <list>
        <Building>
            <code>BuildingExcess</code>
            <value>600</value>
        </Building>
        <Content>
            <code>ContentExcess</code>
            <value>600</value>
        </Content>
    </list>
    <list>
        <Building>
            <code>BuildingExcess</code>
            <value>700</value>
        </Building>
        <Content>
            <code>ContentExcess</code>
            <value>600</value>
        </Content>
    </list>
    <list>
        <Building>
            <code>BuildingExcess</code>
            <value>600</value>
        </Building>
        <Content>
            <code>ContentExcess</code>
            <value>400</value>
        </Content>
    </list>
    <list>
        <Building>
            <code>BuildingExcess</code>
            <value>700</value>
        </Building>
        <Content>
            <code>ContentExcess</code>
            <value>400</value>
        </Content>
    </list> 
</resultset>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your two lists are always `building` and `content`, and they're elements of your payload (or some variable), you can use the following dataweave code to achieve your desired output:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%var input = {
    "building":[  
          {  
             "code":"BuildingExcess",
             "value":"600"
          },
          {  
             "code":"BuildingExcess",
             "value":"700"
          }
       ],
    "content":[  
          {  
             "code":"ContentExcess",
             "value":"600"
          },
          {  
             "code":"ContentExcess",
             "value":"400"
          }
    ]   
}
---
resultset: {( 
    flatten (input.content map ((cont) -> input.building map 
        list: {
            Building: $,
            Content: cont
        })
    )
)}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<resultset>
  <list>
    <Building>
      <code>BuildingExcess</code>
      <value>600</value>
    </Building>
    <Content>
      <code>ContentExcess</code>
      <value>600</value>
    </Content>
  </list>
  <list>
    <Building>
      <code>BuildingExcess</code>
      <value>700</value>
    </Building>
    <Content>
      <code>ContentExcess</code>
      <value>600</value>
    </Content>
  </list>
  <list>
    <Building>
      <code>BuildingExcess</code>
      <value>600</value>
    </Building>
    <Content>
      <code>ContentExcess</code>
      <value>400</value>
    </Content>
  </list>
  <list>
    <Building>
      <code>BuildingExcess</code>
      <value>700</value>
    </Building>
    <Content>
      <code>ContentExcess</code>
      <value>400</value>
    </Content>
  </list>
</resultset>
```